# Postconf errors (valid_hostname) after install mail-utils

Tags: 16.04, postfix, mailutils

mail-utils did a number on my system.

I would like to get my system back to before mail-utils was installed.

I tried un-installing it and posting at other Ubuntu forums.

It is messing with my update,clean,and remove script.

```
postconf: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: 7

postconf: fatal: unable to use my own hostname
Use of uninitialized value $destinations in scalar chomp at /var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.config line 221.

Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
postconf: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: 7
postconf: fatal: unable to use my own hostname
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is in mail.log

```
Jan  3 17:08:02 7 postfix/sendmail[6178]: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: 7
Jan  3 17:08:02 7 postfix/sendmail[6178]: fatal: unable to use my own hostname
```

I have a clone image, but it's 10 days old. :-(

I guess I am the first to have this problem.

I hope someone can help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your system hostname is set to a number, not a name.  Read `/etc/hostname` to check.

Depending on how postfix is configured, it may be getting this from your `/etc/hostname`.  Try updating this with the command

```
sudo hostname <newhostname>
```

If this fixes the problem you'll need to make it permanent by editing it in `/etc/hostname` which contains only the hostname and `/etc/hosts` if you have a reference to it somewhere in that file.

Or, check your postfix configuration in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to see if you have overridden anything there which may cause this issue.

Comment: 7 is in hostname. What do I use for my hostname?

Comment: A name consisting of letters and numbers, but not starting with a number, such as "fixit7".  Note that a segment of a full hostname in DNS can in theory entirely consist of a number, but not everything supports it when used as hostname for a machine like this.

Answer (score 2):

If Your computer doesn't belong to any domain, just clean box "Domain Search" in ethernet configuration, correct file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and then run:

```
apt-get install postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem with :

```
apt install mailutils
```

and when I receive hostname error then

1. I've edited `/etc/postfix/main.cf`
2. Go to line: `myhostname=`
3. Write your domain name. For example: `example.com`.
4. Run again : `apt install mailutils`
5. Send mail :

Execute Linux command

```
 echo "This is the body of an encrypted email" | mail -s "This is the
    subject line" 3321@mailinator.com
```

6. Go to public mail

https://www.mailinator.com/v4/public/inboxes.jsp?to=3321